# Can anyone tell me why the program is not showing 'hello' and just showing a simple white screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside6, pyqt6

When I try to run this, it starts and runs perfectly fine with no error and a white screen just like any other normal PySide6 program but it doesn't show the text that i expected to see.

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *

class View(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.addText("Hello!")
        self.scene = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.scene.show()

app = QApplication([])
View()
app.exec()
```

i expected a white screen with hello text but there's just a white screen with nothing

Comment: Your naming seems quite confused: you create a subclass of QGraphicsScene that you name `View`, and an instance of QGraphicsView that you name `self.scene`. You should pay more attention to these aspects: those two classes are obviously closely related, but their purposes and functionalities are very different, and you cannot confuse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing assigning `View` object to any variable, so it gets garbage collected nearly immediately. Assign it to something and it will stay open: `window = View()`

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `View()` to a variable to avoid it being garbage collected, then show it like this to print the hello text:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *

class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
        self.scene().addText("Hello!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    view = View()
    view.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

`View` object has no reference to it. However, you can fix this by assigning the `View` object to a variable.

```
app = QApplication([])
view = View()
app.exec()
```